# Ruby transform hash based on mapping

Tags: ruby, hash, rename

Let's say I have a mapping of how I want a hash to turn out, along with new key names like this:

```
JSON_MAP = {
  image: {
    id: :id,
    media_url: :url,
    time: :duration,
    timestamp: :time_posted,
    text_caption: :caption,
    metadata: {
      camera: :camera_type,
      flash: :camera_flash
    }
  },
  viewers: {
    views: :view_count,
    likes: :likes_count
  }
}
```

and I have a hash like this:

```
{
  image: {
    id: 1,
    media_url: 'http://placekitten.com',
    nsfw: false,
    time: 4,
    timestamp: 14149292,
    text_caption: "I'm a kitten",
    metadata: {
      camera: 'iPhone',
      flash: true
    }
  },
  viewers: {
    views: 50,
    likes: 15
  },
  extras: {
    features: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
}
```

I only want it to transform the data so it ends up like:

```
{
  image: {
    id: 1,
    url: 'http://placekitten.com',
    duration: 4,
    time_posted: 14149292,
    caption: "I'm a kitten",
    metadata: {
      camera: 'iPhone',
      flash: true
    }
  },
  viewers: {
    view_count: 50,
    likes_count: 15
  }
}
```

Basically, renaming all the keys based on the source map, and deleting any keys that don't match the source map...

Comment: You need to show your attempt to solve the problem. Merely showing us the desired data suggests you want us to write the code for you, which isn't what SO is for. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages. Also “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421)” is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain your desired result using recursion.

```
def convert(mapper, hsh)
  mapper.each_with_object({}) do |(k,o),h|
    next unless hsh.key?(k)
    if o.is_a? Hash
      h[k] = convert(o, hsh[k])
    else
      h[o] = hsh[k]
    end
  end
end
```

Assuming `h` equals your second hash,

```
convert(JSON_MAP, h)    
  #=> { :image=>{
  #       :id=>1,
  #       :url=>"http://placekitten.com",
  #       :duration=>4,
  #       :time_posted=>14149292,
  #       :caption=>"I'm a kitten",
  #       :metadata=>{
  #         :camera_type=>"iPhone",
  #         :camera_flash=>true
  #       }
  #     },
  #     :viewers=>{
  #       :view_count=>50,
  #       :likes_count=>15
  #     }
  #   }
```

Comment: Hrm, that didn't work for me - saying "recurse" is not a method?

Comment: I initially had two methods: `convert` and `recurse`, then realized I only needed one, `convert`, but I forgot to change `recurse` to `convert` in the body. I've made the correction.

Comment: Please elaborate. The method works fine for the two hashes in your question.

Comment: Ah I found that it fails if a hash isn't there.. so if metadata didn't exist, it failed.

Comment: Good catch. It would also fail if there were no key `:image` or `:viewers`. Your fix seems to cover all those cases.